# Login failed for user sa - while using ASP.NET and SQL Server containers

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, entity-framework-core

I have ASP.NET Web API application. I've been using SQL Server as container for development and now I want to dockerize entire application using those two containers.

docker-compose.yaml file looks like this:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Testpass123!@#
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'Testpass123!@#' -Q "SELECT 1"
      interval: 10s
      retries: 15
    networks:
      - mutual-network
  
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mutual-network

networks:
  mutual-network:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["update.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./update.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "update.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "update.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "update.dll"]
```

Here is my connection string:

> "Server=172.18.0.2;Database=testDB;User=sa;Password=Testpass123!@#;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

when I make a call to an API endpoint, it gives me very long error message with headline:

> Login failed for username 'sa'.

**UPDATE:**
I think both SA_PASSWORD and MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD works, I had second one in compose file at first and changed it later.

I have modified both Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Testpass123_
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 'Testpass123_' -Q "SELECT 1"
      interval: 10s
      retries: 15
    networks:
      - mutual-network
  
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mutual-network

networks:
  mutual-network:
```

and

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["update.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./update.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "update.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "update.csproj" -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef && \
    PATH=$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools && \
    dotnet ef migrations add Initialization

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "update.dll"]
```

also, I added portion of code to Program.cs before app.Run() call:

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope()) {
    var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    if (context.Database.GetMigrations().Any()) {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

error is the following line:

> Cannot open database "testDB" requested by the login. The login
> failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

**SOLUTION:**
okay, as you may already have noticed, I try to run migrations in another layer where that Migrations folder should be located. Therefore, that portion of code is useless for that situation. I created migrations by myself in local directory and then built the image. Now everything works as expected, migrations are run before server starts and database is present for API calls.

Comment: Aside... when you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) did you notice that the environment variable to use for the sa password is `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD`? It used to be `SA_PASSWORD` a long time ago, but that is deprecated.

Comment: Sometimes special shell characters get gazzumped. If you open a Docker interactive terminal to the SQL Server container and type `export` do you see the correct value stored in the environment variable?

Comment: Have you read the rest of the "very long error message" in the Docker container's console? It might contain some very important information like "Couldn't find database requested by user." Where do you create the database named `testDB`? It has to exist already before a connection string with `Database=testDB;` can succeed. See also the image documentation link above where it mentions [using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database.](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize)

Comment: I will update question with what I tried while I was waiting for answers.